# How to prove the following equality dealing with functions of indexed sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove

$f( \bigcup\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in\Lambda\} = \bigcup \{f(U_\alpha):\alpha \in \Lambda\} $

More specifically I am having issues with the $\supseteq$ part of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y \in f(\cup_\alpha U_\alpha) $ **iff** there is some $x \in \cup_\alpha U_\alpha$ such that $y=f(x)$
**iff** there is some $\alpha$ and some $x \in U_\alpha$ such that $y=f(x)$
**iff** $y \in \cup_\alpha f(U_\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \bigcup_\Lambda f(U_\alpha)$. Then for some $\alpha_0 \in \Lambda$, we have $x \in f(U_{\alpha_0})$. Since $U_{\alpha_0} \subset \bigcup_{\Lambda} U_\alpha$, we also have $x \in f(\bigcup_\Lambda U_\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Each $U_\alpha$ is contained in $\;\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda} U_\alpha$, so each $\;f(U_\alpha)$ is contained in $\;f\bigl(\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda} U_\alpha\bigr)$.